# how do I save my data (one-to-many) using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I'm following this example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/

In the case of the example: it's a one-to-many relationship between departments vs employees (assuming employes can only work in 1 department).

In the example, the a new department is created every time and then new employees were attached to it.

what changes needs to happen if the department is already existing? like perhaps I ran the example again and want to add more employees to an existing department.

I searched the net but all examples/guides I came across assumes a new department is created every time.

My guess is that I need to setup a DAO function that searches the DB and returns a department datatype?

Thanks! :)

**Here's the code as mentioned in viralpatel.net**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Department department = new Department();
    department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
    session.save(department);

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "1212");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "4343");

    emp1.setDepartment(department);
    emp2.setDepartment(department);

    session.save(emp1);
    session.save(emp2);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `get` of the Session object to get the object from databse:

```
session.get(Department.class, id);
```

You can see the full documentation in the following ling: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Answer (score 1):

that was the same question i asked a while ago,
you can add People to existing Department simply by load/get Department from database first

```
Department department = session.get(Department.class,new Long(10)); // i assume you are using Long for primary key

Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "1212");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "4343");

emp1.setDepartment(department);
emp2.setDepartment(department);
```